# How to extract VPCID, PrivateSubnet1, PublicSubnet1, S3BucketName & DBSubnetGroup automatically after executing [aws cloudformation create-stack]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I ran this command:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name my-stackname --template-body file://stack.yml --parameters file://stack-params.json
```

And got this result:

```
arams.json

{
    "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:343434345343:stack/some-stack-name/43434f-sed434-1147-867c-098sdfs09sdd"
}
```

However, I'm looking for a way to programmatically/automatically capture values for ***VPCID, PrivateSubnet1, PrivateSubnet2, PublicSubnet1, PublicSubnet2, S3BucketName & DBSubnetGroup*** based on the values in the output section of the base stack created above.

I don't want to login to my aws cloudformation service console to manually copy and paste these values.

Is there a way to automatically extract that data, maybe some script of some kind?
I could pipe the output of the above command to another program and parse the data if that data was in the output but all I get in the output is the stackid.

How do I get the ***VPCID, PrivateSubnet1, PrivateSubnet2, PublicSubnet1, PublicSubnet2, S3BucketName & DBSubnetGroup*** based on the values in the output section of the base stack created above?

Comment: You'll need to wait until the stack creation has completed to be able to get the output values, but you could use the awscli (aws cloudformation describe-stacks) and then retrieve the Stacks[].Outputs[] values (using jq, for example).

Comment: Thank you @jarmod I was leaning toward that direction when I checked the Cloudformation API. Maybe I'll put together a quick solution using your guidance and post it below just for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`aws cloudformation wait`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/wait/stack-create-complete.html) command to wait for your stack to finish before checking the output values. For example:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
    --stack-name my-stackname \
    --template-body file://stack.yml \
    --parameters file://stack-params.json

aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete \
    --stack-name my-stackname

aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
    --stack-name my-stackname \
    --query "Stacks[0].Outputs"
```

If you want to get the stack outputs one by one, you can use a query such as:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
    --stack-name my-stackname \
    --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='VPCID'].OutputValue" \
    --output text
```

Note that for `wait`, you need to use `stack-update-complete` if you are doing an update rather than a create.

Comment: Thank you; that's exactly what my thinking was